# How to adjust alignment and column width (tabular)?

Tags: tables, align

I would like columns 2 and 3 to be aligned to the right hand side. However, it does not seem to work.
Though several questions relate to this issue and my question will probably be marked as duplicate, I don't know what is wrong about my table.

I would be thankful for any hints, e.g. on possibly missing packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}                           
\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.1\textwidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.05\textwidth}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.05\textwidth}}
\hline
& h\_1 & h\_2  \\ 
\hline
x\_1 & 10.80 & 11.68 \\ 
x\_2 & 1.96 & 1.94 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your columns are too narrow for the data, latex warns:

```
Overfull \hbox (5.5268pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--9
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 10.80|  

Overfull \hbox (5.5268pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--10
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 11.68|  

Overfull \hbox (0.52678pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--10
[]|\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1.96|
```

It can not align unbreakable  text that is wider than the specified column width

It works if the columns are wider, also you want `\raggedleft`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}                           
\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.1\textwidth}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\hline
& h\_1 & h\_2  \\ 
\hline
x\_1 & 10.80 & 11.68 \\ 
x\_2 & 1.96 & 1.94 \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Although for numeric columns it is usually better to use `dcolumn` or `siunitx` to align on the decimal point.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my problem with overfull hboxes. I actually have a wide table (h_1 to h_24) which I want to print in landscape format. In order to get the table aligned correctly on one page I need to reduce fontsize to tiny. Since the spaces between columns in my opinion are too wide and could be reduced I tried to manually fix column width which then causes the alignment to fail.

Comment: Ah, it seems like using the table-format option in siunitx more thoroughly helps a lot and my tables look much better. Many thanks also to @LaRiFaRi for the nice example!

Comment: @Aki the column sep is `\tabcolsep` which is a fixed size (6pt usually) it does not automatically reduce if you are using a small font size, you often need `\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}` or some such command in those cases.

Answer (score 4):

Just in addition to David's answer, here is the `siunitx`-version:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}  
\usepackage{booktabs}    

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-text-alignment=right, table-format=2.2]}}
            \toprule
            & {h\_1} & {h\_2}  \\ 
            \midrule
            x\_1 & 10.80 & 11.68 \\ 
            x\_2 & 1.96 & 1.94 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 my answer said why the code in the question didn't work, but the OP should do this:-)